# Overlaying Image But Where No Graphic Other Div Selectable

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, html5-canvas

At the top of my site you'll find the featured content loop below a big top circus tent and from this I have a png image of some curtains of which I want to overlay.

Now the above is not the problem, what I wish to achieve is that only where the curtains are, it should not effect the featured content loop whereas you can still interact.

Is it possible and how would I achieve overlaying my curtains which pin to the side and only have it so that the featured content loop is still fully intractable other than where my curtains visibly are?

[image]
[image]
[image]
"Curtains over
lap but in this area
you can still do standard
onClick events, highlighting
text, prety much what you can do inside of a normal div."

**Additional**

In layers, imagine only the curtains is over the content behind and only when you are on the curtains then the content behind is not interact-able otherwise hovering over the featured loop content is.

Update:

Looking at mapping around the red parts of my curtains, not the shadow, I used [this](http://brittonkerin.com/image_region_selector/irs_demo.html) which resulted in the following outcome:

```
{
  {'x': 62, 'y': 375}
  {'x': 59, 'y': 367}
  {'x': 59, 'y': 350}
  {'x': 56, 'y': 326}
  {'x': 53, 'y': 271}
  {'x': 51, 'y': 184}
  {'x': 60, 'y': 170}
  {'x': 65, 'y': 167}
  {'x': 93, 'y': 164}
  {'x': 126, 'y': 158}
  {'x': 169, 'y': 148}
  {'x': 208, 'y': 137}
  {'x': 251, 'y': 121}
  {'x': 282, 'y': 108}
  {'x': 335, 'y': 83}
  {'x': 365, 'y': 66}
  {'x': 400, 'y': 45}
  {'x': 420, 'y': 31}
  {'x': 441, 'y': 16}
  {'x': 455, 'y': 2}
  {'x': 504, 'y': 2}
  {'x': 535, 'y': 29}
  {'x': 597, 'y': 69}
  {'x': 660, 'y': 101}
  {'x': 731, 'y': 129}
  {'x': 788, 'y': 147}
  {'x': 841, 'y': 159}
  {'x': 888, 'y': 167}
  {'x': 901, 'y': 169}
  {'x': 905, 'y': 174}
  {'x': 914, 'y': 183}
  {'x': 912, 'y': 238}
  {'x': 910, 'y': 291}
  {'x': 906, 'y': 331}
  {'x': 905, 'y': 348}
  {'x': 905, 'y': 360}
  {'x': 937, 'y': 361}
  {'x': 952, 'y': 358}
  {'x': 960, 'y': 356}
  {'x': 961, 'y': 336}
  {'x': 943, 'y': 208}
  {'x': 939, 'y': 175}
  {'x': 941, 'y': 165}
  {'x': 940, 'y': 142}
  {'x': 924, 'y': 143}
  {'x': 913, 'y': 146}
  {'x': 877, 'y': 143}
  {'x': 791, 'y': 129}
  {'x': 709, 'y': 105}
  {'x': 647, 'y': 80}
  {'x': 597, 'y': 55}
  {'x': 548, 'y': 27}
  {'x': 519, 'y': 5}
  {'x': 510, 'y': 0}
  {'x': 450, 'y': 0}
  {'x': 444, 'y': 4}
  {'x': 422, 'y': 19}
  {'x': 387, 'y': 42}
  {'x': 347, 'y': 65}
  {'x': 303, 'y': 85}
  {'x': 230, 'y': 112}
  {'x': 192, 'y': 124}
  {'x': 95, 'y': 143}
  {'x': 65, 'y': 146}
  {'x': 44, 'y': 145}
  {'x': 26, 'y': 143}
  {'x': 24, 'y': 169}
  {'x': 23, 'y': 190}
  {'x': 15, 'y': 266}
  {'x': 6, 'y': 333}
  {'x': 0, 'y': 368}
  {'x': 17, 'y': 375}
  {'x': 38, 'y': 376}
  {'x': 50, 'y': 376}
  {'x': 62, 'y': 375}
}
```

Or this rather larger output I've placed in a fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/3dsjxd6e/

Now I am to learn what I have created and how it can be used.

Comment: What site? Can you post some code or URL?

Comment: [My site](http://rafflebananza.com/Desktop/index.html) Sorry I know linking to sites is not good for questions and I do not have enough rep to upload images.

Comment: what kind of interaction are we talking about? can you post an example screenshot or diagram.... what scope of interaction do u need....I kinda have an idea that involves JS but i need to understand scope of interaction

Comment: From what I read I understood that he wants to be able to interact with the div behind the curtains like the curtains wouldnt be there at all. @Sai

Comment: You could use the event.target from the click event in Jquery and from there interpret anything you want to do.

Comment: capture mouse event (enter or leave) and get the coordinates (refer  http://javascript.info/tutorial/mouse-events ) then calculate the coordinates that is covered by the curtain and the rest of the coordinates are open . Use JS to capture mouse event in those open coordinates and call some function to do what you want. This does involve some advanced JS

Comment: Tried to explain a little better, edited question above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution for unedited question:

You can do this in CSS with `pointer-events: none;`.

### Browser Support:

Not great, but not horrible either. http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events

### Solution:

The solution is pretty easy, you just let the curtain overlap the background, using absolute positioning or negative margins.
Then you add `pointer-events: none;` to the overlaying element (curtain) and you will be able to select text or trigger hovers underneath.

### Fiddle:

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/7bwaarww/1/

### Solution to the edited question:

Now that we have a polygon representing the shape of the curtain we can use a PIP (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon) algorithm to decide wether the mouse is over the curtain or not.

### Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/7bwaarww/5/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am looking more for where the curtains are there is nothing happens, such as your on hover would not happen. Otherwise over the part with no curtains it'll work

Comment: Ok this is mostly impossible to do with javascript and css. One solution would be to map out the positions where the curtain is visible and then check those position with the current mouse position. When the positions match your mouse is hovering over the curtain, then you can remove a `.no-events` class which looks like this:
.no-events {
  pointer-events:none;
}

This solution is totally ridiculous and will not perform well. Do not do this!

Comment: Yes I just been looking to no-click events and creating none square divs. i've placed my curtains on the page, guess I'll now go look javascript mapping around objects

Comment: I updated my answer. It's working and the performance is better than expected! @Tim Marshall

Comment: This is absolutely fantastic, I cannot thank you more than enough for your piece of art :)

Comment: Thank you this was fun to do. I'm glad you asked that question ;)

Comment: I've noticed on [my page](http://rafflebananza.com/Desktop/index.html) that sometimes you need to hit refresh from time to time fur the full coordinates to work, sometimes the second testing link is still hover-able over the curtain area. I don't suppose you could look into this and does this site have a PM system to not spam this page?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68574/discussion-between-tim-marshall-and-bastian-hofmann).